# R factor variable losing levels

Tags: r, multi-level

I'm importing data from a SQL table and one-factor variable which should have hundreds of levels is only listed as having one level.  This is causing an error downstream when I try to use datatable to do calculations based on the levels of this variable. I get the error message **"Error in seq.default(start.at, NROW(data), by = by) : wrong sign in 'by' argument"**.  If I import only a small subset of the data for that variable R will show the correct number of levels.

> How can I make sure that R registers the correct number of levels
>   when I import   the data? Or is there a way I can modify the number of
>   levels after importing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain your error is due to wrong factor levels, you can ensure you have the correct set of levels by doing something like:

```
object <- factor(object, levels = unique(object))
```

Comment: Does object reference the factor variable?  Because if I try this:

`df$var<-factor(df$var, levels=unique(df$var))`

It sill shows only 1 level.

Comment: object is the factor variable, yes

Comment: If I do `nlevels(df$var)` it shows the correct number of levels (969), but when I open that dataframe and hover over the column it still says factor with 1 level.

Comment: what does levels(df$var) return?

Comment: Same thing 969, and prints them out.

Comment: I dont know how that all makes sense. Not sure how to help you, sorry